# dynamic content slider in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

I'm hoping someone can provide some advice on getting the slider from the following link to function in Wordpress.  I'm fine working with html, css and a fair amount of php/mysql, however I'm a bit of a noob with WordPress, javascript/jQuery, and how those interact with each other.  I have been searching and don't see this exact problem with a solution, or maybe just don't quite grasp the issue.  I do see that jquery is already enqueued in our WP header.

[kirupa.com slider](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/creating_a_sweet_content_slider.htm)

The reason I'm not using an existing plugin is because both the button and content are dynamic, based on a php/mysql database query and while loops to generate both (think columns of product specs, 3 or 4 visible in the wrapper at once, with buttons at the top bringing a specific product to the leftmost position).  I'm certain I have this aspect to it worked out, and only need to get the animation working - at the moment everything loads correctly but the buttons do not work. I've also tried taking the exact code from the demo to be sure I hadn't fouled things up with my alterations - and it only works if viewed as a standalone page, without all the WordPress headers, footers, etc.

If anyone can point out what needs to be done to get the linked slider functioning in a WordPress template, I can apply that to the actual project, and I'll be eternally grateful!  Perhaps someone has done something similar and can also suggest alternative ways to go about it - either way, I'm all ears!

Thanks in advance!

edit: As a test while trying to sort this out I took source code directly from the above linked demo - this animates as an htm page on it's own, but my attempts at bringing it into the WordPress page templates have failed.  I've left out the css as I don't think that's the issue, but here is the entirety of the code in the body of the demo.  I'm assuming I need to treat the script portion differently - do I need to create a seperate js file and enqueue it? Tag it differently?  I know nothing about this, and appreciate any help.  If you were going to run this within a WordPress template, what would you do differently?

```
    <div id="contentContainer">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="itemOne" class="content">
            <h1>AaBbCc</h1>
            <p>For some reason, everybody likes <strong>Helvetica</strong>. In order to fit in, I have learned to like it as well.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="itemTwo" class="content">
            <h1>AaBbCc</h1>
            <p>Did you know that <strong>Georgia</strong> was designed by 
            Matthew Carter in 1993? Neither did I.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="itemThree" class="content">
            <h1>AaBbCc</h1>
            <p>The Impact font is used by people who want to make a difference 
            in the world.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="itemFour" class="content">
            <h1>AaBbCc</h1>
            <p>By using Comic Sans, the things you write automatically become 
            funnier. Try it out sometime!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="navLinks">
    <ul>
        <li class="itemLinks" data-pos="0px">1</li>
        <li class="itemLinks" data-pos="-550px">2</li>
        <li class="itemLinks" data-pos="-1100px">3</li>
        <li class="itemLinks" data-pos="-1650px">4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="http://www.kirupa.com/html5/examples/js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var links = document.querySelectorAll(".itemLinks");
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        link.addEventListener('click', setPosition, false);
    }

    addClass(links[0], "active");

    function setPosition(e) {
        removeActiveLinks();

        var clickedLink = e.target;
        addClass(clickedLink, "active");

        var position = clickedLink.getAttribute("data-pos");
        wrapper.style.left = position;
    }

    function removeActiveLinks() {
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            removeClass(links[i], "active");
        }
    }

    function addClass(element, classToAdd) {
        var currentClassValue = element.className;

        if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToAdd) == -1) {
            if ((currentClassValue == null) || (currentClassValue === "")) {
                element.className = classToAdd;
            } else {
                element.className += " " + classToAdd;
            }
        }
    }

    function removeClass(element, classToRemove) {
        var currentClassValue = element.className;

        // removing a class value when there is more than one class value present
        // and the class you want to remove is not the first one
        if (currentClassValue.indexOf(" " + classToRemove) != -1) {
            element.className = element.className.replace(" " + classToRemove, "");
            return;
        }

        // removing the first class value when there is more than one class
        // value present
        if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToRemove + " ") != -1) {
            element.className = element.className.replace(classToRemove + " ", "");
            return;
        }

        // removing the first class value when there is only one class value 
        // present
        if (currentClassValue.indexOf(classToRemove) != -1) {
            element.className = element.className.replace(classToRemove, "");
            return;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This Question is *too-broad* as there are many possible solutions and you are not presenting your current code (see [help/on-topic] and [ask]). Basically, what you have to do is a WordPress page template that will render the scripts and contents almost identical to your working standalone version. Look for `wp_enqueue_scripts`, page templates and shortcodes.

Comment: Thanks - I've added the demo code to the original question.  I realize it's a broad question but I know little about javascript, jQuery, or getting them working in WordPress (if I had my way, we would have gone another way).  I'm reading into the wp_enqueue_script now and will give that a shot, but any assistance to shorten the trial-and-error will definitely be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  If anyone else stumbles on this and is as new to WP as I am, the script portion needs to be enqueued - this post spells it out nicely:

http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-load-scripts-in-wordpress-themes/#.UkBv7T8TPTo

The entire script portion was saved in a js file as is, and placed in the theme folder.  On my project I registered it in the functions.php per the instructions I've linked to, and enqueued it in php on the actual project page since it's only needed on that one page.